# Aside using alliteration in a rap lyrics, what else can you do to improve the flow of a song?

Tags: lyrics

Aside using alliteration in a rap lyrics, what else can you do to improve the flow of a song?

> How much wood would a woodchuck chuck

Alliteration can improve the flow of a rap lyrics, what other techniques can you use to improve the flow?

Comment: This is too broad to be answered. We are not a question and answer site, so you need to make your question more focused.